# Search friends' posts on Facebook

Tags: facebook

When I use the FB search bar it always finds groups or pages, etc. I want to search stuff my friends have posted... for instance I remember last week someone posted or commented on a post about a flood. But searching for flood finds all kinds of global FB stuff, not results relevant to my friends.

Is this possible somehow, it kinda seems an obvious thing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to [Facebook](http://www.facebook.com/help/?faq=203029389733976), to search for relevant content posted by your friends, follow these steps:

> Enter a keyword into the Search Typeahead at the top of the page.
>
> Click on either the Search icon or the "See more results for" option from the drop-down menu.
>   You will land in the "All Results" filter by default.
>
> *Note: pressing enter after typing your query into Search Typeahead will take you to the first Search Typeahead result and not to the "All Results Filter".*
>
> To refine your search to show content only from your friends, select the "Posts by Friends" filter from the menu on the left side of the search results page. This will display search results exclusively from your friends.

Comment: It seems this is no longer the case. The link is dead and the "Posts by Friends" filter no longer seems to exist :(

Answer (score 0):

With this app you can search for your photo albums, videos, notes, status posts and events. You can do the same for your friends if they add the app.
http://raphaelpungin.com/search-for-posts-facebook-app

Comment: Please see the [FAQ#promotion] regarding products/services with which you have a vested interest.